# Hash Table add and print function issues

Tags: c++, hashtable

So I have an assignment and I have to create a hash table. As the title says, I am having issues with the `addItem` and `printTable` function. I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks

**HashTable.h**

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H_
#define HASTABLE_H_

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class HashTable {

public:
    HashTable();
    ~HashTable();

    int hash(string key, const int TABLE_SIZE); // Returns the hash value for the given key, the ASCII values of each character % the table size
    void addItem(string title, string author, int isbn); // Inserts a new item into the table, calls has function on the key title to determine the correct bucket
    int numItemsAtIndex(int index); //Helper function to printTable, counts # of items in each bucket
    void printTable(); //Prints first item of each bucket, includes number of items stored at that bucket

private:
    struct Node
    {
        string title;
        string author;
        int isbn;
        Node* next;
        Node() : title(""), author(""), isbn(0), next(NULL) {}
        Node(string ntitle, string nauthor, int nisbn) : title(ntitle), author(nauthor), isbn(nisbn), next(NULL) {}
    };

    typedef struct Node* Nodeptr;
    static const int TABLE_SIZE = 10;
    Nodeptr Table[TABLE_SIZE];
};
#endif /*HASHTABLE_H_*/
```

**HashTable.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "HashTable.h"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

HashTable::HashTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        Table[i] = new Node;
}

HashTable::~HashTable() {}

int HashTable::hash(string key, const int TABLE_SIZE)
{
    int index, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
        sum += key[i];
    index = sum % TABLE_SIZE;
    return index;
}

void HashTable::addItem(string title, string author, int isbn)
{
    Nodeptr newNode = new Node(title, author, isbn);
    int index = hash(title, TABLE_SIZE);
    if (index == 0)
        Table[index] = newNode;
    else
    {
        Nodeptr tempNode = new Node;
        tempNode = Table[0];
        while (tempNode->next != NULL)
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        newNode = tempNode->next;
    }
}

int HashTable::numItemsAtIndex(int index)
{
    Nodeptr temp = Table[0];
    int counter = 0;
    if (temp->title == "")
        return counter;
    else
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            counter++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    return counter;
}

void HashTable::printTable()
{
    Nodeptr temp = new Node;
    temp = Table[0];
    cout << "Book Hash Table:" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x <= TABLE_SIZE; x++)
    {
        Table[x];
        cout << "Index: "  << x << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << temp->title << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << temp->author << endl;
        cout << "ISBN: " << temp->isbn << endl;
        cout << "Number of Values at this Index: "  << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete temp;
}
```

**HashTest.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HashTable.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    HashTable table;

    table.addItem("Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austen", 12345678);
    table.addItem("Contact", "Carl Sagan", 9999333939);
    table.addItem("The Hunger Games", "Suzanne Collins", 12388888);
    table.addItem("Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowlings", 55555678);
    table.addItem("The Man in the High Castle", "Philip K Dick", 9595959595);
    table.addItem("Bleak House", "Charles Dickens", 47389023849);

    table.printTable();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your destructor delete things? Shouldn't you delete an existing node before replacing it with a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to understand how pointers work, when you use `new` to create a pointer you have to free it with `delete` or you'd have memory leaks. also you need to understand the difference between `int`, `long` and `long long`, the `isbn` variable stores a large number so you need to declare it as `long long`.
Also you need to have a way of finding out if an item in the `Table` array is set or not, you can initialize all items to `NULL` for example.

I fixed your code, hope it'll be helpful for you to understand what you were doing wrong:

## HashTable.hpp

```
    struct Node
    {
        string title;
        string author;
        long long isbn;
        Node* next;
        Node() : title(""), author(""), isbn(0), next(NULL) {}
        Node (string ntitle, string nauthor, long long nisbn) : title(ntitle), author(nauthor), isbn(nisbn), next(NULL) {}
    };

    void addItem(string title, string author, long long isbn);
```

## HashTable.cpp

```
HashTable::HashTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) Table[i] = NULL;
}

HashTable::~HashTable()
{
    Nodeptr cur, temp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (Table[i] != NULL)
        {
            cur = Table[i];
            while (cur != NULL)
            {
                temp = cur;
                cur = cur->next;
                delete (temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int HashTable::hash(string key, const int TABLE_SIZE)
{
    int index, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) sum += key[i];
    index = sum % TABLE_SIZE;
    return index;
}

void HashTable::addItem(string title, string author, long long isbn)
{
    Nodeptr newNode = new Node (title, author, isbn);
    int index = hash (title, TABLE_SIZE);
    if (Table[index] == NULL) Table[index] = newNode;
    else
    {
        Nodeptr tempNode = Table[index];
        while (tempNode->next != NULL) tempNode = tempNode->next;
        tempNode->next = newNode;
    }
}

int HashTable::numItemsAtIndex (int index)
{
    Nodeptr temp = Table[index];
    int counter = 0;
    if (temp == NULL) return counter;
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            counter++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

void HashTable::printTable()
{
    Nodeptr temp;
    cout << "Book Hash Table:" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < TABLE_SIZE; x++)
    {
        temp = Table[x];
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << "Index: "  << x << endl;
            cout << "Title: " << temp->title << endl;
            cout << "Author: " << temp->author << endl;
            cout << "ISBN: " << temp->isbn << endl;
            cout << "Number of Values at this Index: " << numItemsAtIndex (x);
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

## HashTest.cpp

```
int main()
{
    HashTable table;

    table.addItem("Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austen", 12345678L);
    table.addItem("Contact", "Carl Sagan", 9999333939);
    table.addItem("The Hunger Games", "Suzanne Collins", 12388888L);
    table.addItem("Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowlings", 55555678L);
    table.addItem("The Man in the High Castle", "Philip K Dick", 9595959595L);
    table.addItem("Bleak House", "Charles Dickens", 47389023849L);

    table.printTable();

    return 0;
}
```

## Result

```
Book Hash Table:
--------------------------
Index: 3
Title: The Hunger Games
Author: Suzanne Collins
ISBN: 12388888
Number of Values at this Index: 1

Index: 4
Title: Pride and Prejudice
Author: Jane Austen
ISBN: 12345678
Number of Values at this Index: 1

Index: 6
Title: Contact
Author: Carl Sagan
ISBN: 9999333939
Number of Values at this Index: 1

Index: 7
Title: The Man in the High Castle
Author: Philip K Dick
ISBN: 9595959595
Number of Values at this Index: 2

Index: 8
Title: Harry Potter
Author: J.K. Rowlings
ISBN: 55555678
Number of Values at this Index: 1
```

Comment: Hey why do you have the constructor :  You have Table[i] = NULL and why would Table[i] = new Node, like I previously had, not work? Just want to know for future reference. Thanks

Comment: For validation of set items within Table, u can set all items to Nodeptr and use if (Table[index]->title) == ""

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment, but I found the space lacking.

There is quite a lot of odd statements in your code.

```
Nodeptr temp = new Node;
temp = Table[0];
```

and in `printTable`

```
Table[x];
```

You need to decide a strategy for collisions. Your `Node`indicates that you want a linked list as your bucket, but the `addItem` member doesn't address this.

Why is `index = 0`special in `addItem`?

```
if (index == 0)
    Table[index] = newNode;
```

You need to rethink what each member needs to accomplish.

Comment: he is accounting for collision.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashTable::HashTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        Table[i] = NULL;
}

void HashTable::addItem(string title, string author, int isbn)
{
    Nodeptr newNode = new Node(title, author, isbn);
    int index = hash(title, TABLE_SIZE);
    if (Table[index] == NULL)
        Table[index] = newNode;
    else
    {
        Nodeptr tempNode = Table[index];
        while (tempNode->next != NULL)
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        tempNode = newNode->next;
    }
}

int HashTable::numItemsAtIndex(int index)
{
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= TABLE_SIZE)) return 0;
    Nodeptr temp = Table[index];
    int counter = 0;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            counter++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    return counter;
}


void HashTable::printTable()
{

    cout << "Book Hash Table:" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < TABLE_SIZE; x++)
    {
        if (Table[x] == NULL) continue;
        NodePtr temp = Table[x];
        do
        {
        cout << "Index: "  << x << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << temp->title << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << temp->author << endl;
        cout << "ISBN: " << temp->isbn << endl;
        cout << "Number of Values at this Index: "  << endl;
        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
        } while (temp != NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Print function still acting up as well as not displaying the items added.

Comment: output doesn't have the info that we added and it crashes through the 10th iteration

Comment: i have print function included in my answer. Are you using that function? Because your original print function has an outbounds exception (accessing beyond 10th element) and that would explain the crash after 10th iteration.

Comment: Yeah I tried yours. This is the error I am getting: size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
  { // return length of sequence
  return (this->_Mysize());
  }